# Constructing a URL for an image export

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm trying to use a map server to create and export an image, as well as have some zoom in functionality. However, I'm not exactly sure how to implement this through HTML/javascripting. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="center">
            <button type="button" id="In" onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom in</button>
            <button type="button" id="Out" onclick="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button>
            <button type="button" id="Full" onclick="fullExtent">FullExtent</button>
</div>






<script>
    var sURL= "http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer/export?bbox=";
    var xmin= -180;
    var ymin=-90;
    var xmax=180;
    var ymax=90;
    var bbox=xmin+","+ymin+","+xmax+","+ymax;


    function makeImage(URL){
        var img = '<div id="pic"><img src="'+URL+'" width="800" height="400" /><p></p></div>'; 
        return img;
    }

    function zoomIn(){
        xmin= xmin/2;
        ymin= ymin/2;
        xmax= xmax/2;
        ymax= ymax/2
        var URL= sURL+bbox;
        return URL;
        makeImage(URL);
    }
    function zoomOut(){
        xmin= xmin/2;
        ymin=ymin/2;
        xmax=xmax/2;
        ymax=ymax/2
        var URL= sURL+bbox;
        return URL; 
        makeImage(URL);
    }
    function fullExtent(){
        xmin= -180;
        ymin=-90;
        xmax=180;
        ymax=90;
        var URL= sURL+bbox;
        return URL; 
        makeImage(URL);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would edit your script like so (http://jsfiddle.net/fsh6p77L/):

```
<div class="center">
            <button type="button" id="In" onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom in</button>
            <button type="button" id="Out" onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
            <button type="button" id="Full" onclick="fullExtent()">FullExtent</button>
            <div id="pic"></div>
</div>






<script>
    var sURL= "http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer/export?bbox=";
    var xmin= -180;
    var ymin=-90;
    var xmax=180;
    var ymax=90;
    var bbox=xmin+","+ymin+","+xmax+","+ymax;


    function makeImage(URL){
        var img = '<img src="'+URL+'" width="800" height="400" /><p></p>'; 
        document.getElementById("pic").innerHTML = img;
    }

    function zoomIn(){
        xmin= xmin/2;
        ymin= ymin/2;
        xmax= xmax/2;
        ymax= ymax/2
        var URL= sURL+bbox;
        makeImage(URL);
    }
    function zoomOut(){
        xmin= xmin/2;
        ymin=ymin/2;
        xmax=xmax/2;
        ymax=ymax/2
        var URL= sURL+bbox;
        makeImage(URL);
    }
    function fullExtent(){
        xmin= -180;
        ymin=-90;
        xmax=180;
        ymax=90;
        var URL= sURL+bbox;
        makeImage(URL);
    }
</script>
```